# Understand IAM Principal

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-ecs, amazon-kms

I am try to understand what does below policy means specially `Principal` `Service` part, I have attached it to a AWS KMS key.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": [
                "kms:Encrypt",
                "kms:Decrypt",
                "kms:GenerateDataKey"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Does it means that my software(running inside a docker in fargate) can call this KMS key to encrypt data?

OR

Does it means that ecs itself can call this KMS key to encrypt some thing?

Comment: How did it go with the issue? The IAM Principals for ECS are still unclear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case it **means both things**. This is because [IAM Roles for Tasks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-iam-roles.html) as well as [ECS task execution IAM role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_execution_IAM_role.html) use the **same principle** of `ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com`.

You would have to specify exactly which role in `Resource` can use the key. For now with `*` only, any role, either `IAM Roles for Tasks` or `ECS task execution IAM role` can use such key.

Comment: You got the first part correct, but I think you are wrong about the `resource` reference.   The poster identified this as a policy that was attached to a KMS Key, so I assume this means he is showing us a KMS Key Policy (not an IAM policy).  Even though Key Policies have a resource field, use of '*' refers to this key only (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/key-policies.html).  Key Policies can have a condition to filter on, depending on the available filters for that service.